# How to set .gitmodules so that contributors don't have to fork also submodule?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I have a library on github

```
my_library
  |-- my_submodule
```

with `.gitmodules`

```
[submodule "my_submodule"]
    path = my_submodule
    url = ../my_submodule.git
    branch = master
```

My contributors now need to fork both repo `my_library` and repo `my_submodule` to their github, and then be able to `git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/<contributor_user_name>/my_library`

Otherwise they will get

```
...
Submodule 'my_submodule' (https://github.com/<contributor_user_name>/fastai-docs.git) registered for path 'docs'
Cloning into 'my_submodule'...
Username for 'https://github.com': <contributor_user_name>   
Password for 'https://<contributor_user_name>@github.com': 
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/<contributor_user_name>/my_submodule.git/' not found
fatal: clone of 'https://github.com/<contributor_user_name>/my_submodule.git' into submodule path 'my_submodule' failed
```

How should I do, so contributors don't need to fork also `my_submodule` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify a *relative path* as the submodule's URL, Git will assume that the submodule's repository is available in the same location as the main repository.

From the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#_commands):

> If the URL is given relative to the superproject’s repository, the presumption is the superproject and submodule repositories will be kept together in the same relative location, and only the superproject’s URL needs to be provided. git-submodule will correctly locate the submodule using the relative URL in `.gitmodules`.

If you don't want your contributors to have to clone the submodule's repository as well, you should specify its absolute URL in `.gitmodules`:

```
[submodule "my_submodule"]
    path = my_submodule
    url = https://github.com/<your_user_name>/my_submodule.git
    branch = master
```

That way, Git will fetch the submodule's repository from your GitHub account, rather than theirs.

Comment: This will force the `ssh` users to clone the repo in two method. Root repo will be cloned using `ssh` and the submodule will be cloned using `https`, hence two authentication methods.

Answer (score 1):

You committed a `.gitmodules` file where the `url` is relative to the root repo origin.

Replace this relative url with an absolute url to your repo : `https://github.com/RichardYY/fastai-docs.git`

---

Users (including yourself) may use git config [`url.[replacement url].insteadOf`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-urlltbasegtinsteadOf) (example in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Kovrinic/ea5e7123ab5c97d451804ea222ecd78a)) to connect to a different repo on their local clone :

```
# for example : if you want to access this repo through ssh on your local clone :
git config url."git@github.com:RichardYY/fastai-docs.git".insteadOf https://github.com/RichardYY/fastai-docs.git
```